# Any shared workspace in the DC Metro area where I can build/weld bike frames?

Tags: framebuilding

Anyone in the DC metro area know of a community workspace that I could join to learn to build bike frames? I'm not looking for any equipment or lessons, just a space where I can work.

I've been looking for a space for a while in this area but haven't been able to find anyplace. Any plugs would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never heard of a *community* shop which builds frames in the DC area. There may be a custom bike shop somewhere in DC which would allow you to use their shop for a price. Your best bet would be heading to either [Phoenix Bikes](https://www.phoenixbikes.org/) on Columbia Pike, or [Velocity Bike Coop](https://velocitycoop.org/) in Alexandria. Neither of those shops have welding equipment, but the volunteers probably would know of any community frame building shops in the area. I really like the folks at Velocity; very knowledgeable.